# Washing or rinsing fish and seafood

Tags: food-safety, fish, cleaning, seafood

Do you wash or rinse your fish before cooking it? I usually don't, but I'm not sure whether I'm right or wrong.

Well, ok, I guess it's probably unnecessary in most cases but, what if we're making a raw fish dish like a ceviche? Does that scenario changes the rules?

Same question goes to seafood of all types: mussels, clams, shrimps, so on...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in all things: IT DEPENDS and always try to buy the freshest seafood as possible and consume ASAP.

Fish, depending on the fishmonger, sometimes I will rinse a whole fish it if there is blood or innards still in there; I will make certain after to dry it out completely before using.

For filets and portioned fish or shelled shrimps, no, i will only dry it out.

For shellfish like mussels, clams, I will rinse them and let them soak in cold salted water (I never tried the corn meal trick, google it).

For raw unshelled shrimps, I will clean them out and rinse after.

For your question about Ceviche, I will use the above guide (my own) to prepare the fish before cutting and marinating.

Comment: What exactly is the guide you refer to for Ceviche? Rinsing it before cutting it and marinating? If that's the case, sounds great to me. Regarding shellfish, I never tried rinsing them in salted water so I'll do that. Thanks for your input.